# How sort recursively by maximum file size and count files?

Tags: bash

I'm beginner in bash programming. I want to display head -n $1 results of sorting files
by size in /etc/*.  The problem is that at final search, I must know how many directories and files has processed.

I compose following code:

```
#!/bash/bin
let countF=0;   
let countD=0;
for file in $(du -sk /etc/* |sort +0n | head $1); do
 if [ -f  "file" ] then
   echo $file;
   let countF=countF+1;
else if [ -d  "file" ] then 
   let countD=countD+1;
fi
done
echo $countF
echo $countD
```

I have errors at execution. How use find with du, because I must search recursively?

Comment: Please post the errors. We can't see them from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash      # directory and program reversed
let countF=0     # semicolon not needed (several more places)
let countD=0
while read -r file; do
    if [ -f  "$file" ]; then     # missing dollar sign and semicolon
        echo $file
        let countF=countF+1  # could also be: let countF++
    else if [ -d  "$file" ]; then     # missing dollar sign and semicolon
        let countD=countD+1
    fi
done < <(du -sk /etc/* |sort +0n | head $1)    # see below
echo $countF
echo $countD
```

Changing the loop from a `for` to a `while` allows it to work properly in case filenames contain spaces.

I'm not sure what version of sort you have, but I'll take your word for it that the argument is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bash/bin`.
2. I don't know what that argument to `sort` is supposed to be.  Maybe you meant `sort -r -n`?
3. Your use of head is wrong.  Giving head file arguments causes it to ignore its standard input, so in general it's an error to both pipe something to head and give it a file argument.  Besides that, "$1" refers to the script's first argument.  Did you maybe mean `head -n 1`, or were you trying to make the number of lines processed configurable from an argument to the script:  `head -n"$1"`.
4. In your `if` tests, you're not referencing your loop variable:  it should read `"$file"`, not `"file"`.
5. Not that the bash parser cares, but you should try to indent sanely.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby    

fc=0
dc=0
a=Dir["/etc/*"].inject([]) do |x,f|
    fc+=1 if File.file?(f)
    dc+=1 if File.directory?(f)
    x<<f
end
puts a.sort
puts "number of files: #{fc}"
puts "number of directories: #{dc}"
```

Comment: Showing an ruby implementation is not going to help solve his/her problems with bash.

Comment: If he is not using bash in the first place, he will not have a bash problem. So why does using Ruby (or any other language for that matter) not solve his bash problem? you asked a strange question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash      # directory and program reversed
let countF=0     # semicolon not needed (several more places)
let countD=0
while read -r file; do
    if [ -f  "$file" ]; then     # missing dollar sign and semicolon
        echo $file
        let countF=countF+1  # could also be: let countF++
    else if [ -d  "$file" ]; then     # missing dollar sign and semicolon
        let countD=countD+1
    fi
done < <(du -sk /etc/* |sort +0n | head $1)    # see below
echo $countF
echo $countD
```

I tried instead of file variable the /etc/* but I don't see a result. the idea is to sort all files by size from a directories and subdirectories and display $1 results ordered by
size of the files. In this process I must know how many files and dirs contains the directory where
I did the search.